# Django apache2 KeyError for SECRET_KEY with environment variable

Tags: django, apache2, django-settings

I try to deploy django on a debian server.

To protect the secret key i store them in a environment variable.
I edit `/etc/profile` an add:

`SECRET_KEY="123456789....";
export SECRET_KEY`

I tested if the variable is set with `printenv | grep SECRET_KEY` and `echo $SECRET_KEY`.

It works fine but if i open the website i get

`Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

and in the error.log from apache:

`....
raise KeyError(key) from None
[Tue Sep 17 14:11:20.062194 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13523:tid 140622223152896] [client 123.456.78.910:50361] KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
....`

Why django can't read the environment variable?

Comment: Where's your code to get the secret key from the environment variable? Show us that part of settings.py

Comment: I was same issue with nginx then I found I need to put environment variable into uWSGI (or guncorn) and put them into nginx (or appache) too. the way for guncorn and uWSGI is put them into your uWSGI `. ini` file like https://coderwall.com/p/93jakg/multiple-env-vars-with-uwsgi. hope it help

Comment: I think the reason Django can't read the file because Django running with another user. every user just can access to its environment variable.

Comment: settings.py: `SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']`. @dirkgroten

Comment: @mehdi is there a way to make a global environment variable for all users?

Comment: @Basti I can't found any way when I was trying run Django on my host but attention i'm almost new to OS knowladge so it is possible that a way exist for your goal but I don't know about.are you tried my way?is it worked?

Comment: Now i store the SECRET_KEY in a file. Thanks!